# UPDATE Query WHERE conditions not working in millisecond differences

Tags: mysql

I have working Update query

```
UPDATE contact 
   SET ownerid = '1548'
     , alloted = '1'
     , genby = '1548'
     , leadstatus = '-34-,'
     , callbackdate = '2019-09-25'
     , read = '0' 
 WHERE id = '22484307' 
   AND alloted = '0' 
   AND leadsource = '29' 
   AND `delete` = '0' 
   AND ownerid = '0' 
   AND oldlead != '1'
```

but when this query is updated by two users at the same time (approx) WHERE condition stops working

```
2019-09-25T09:12:27.211547+05:30        9688978 Query   UPDATE `contact` SET `ownerid` = '1548',`alloted` = '1',`genby` = '1548', `leadstatus` = '-34-,', `callbackdate` = '2019-09-25', `read` = '0' WHERE `id` = '22484307' AND `alloted` = '0' AND `leadsource` = '29' AND `delete` = '0' AND `ownerid` = '0' AND `oldlead` != '1'
2019-09-25T09:12:27.400647+05:30        9689052 Query   UPDATE `contact` SET `ownerid` = '1535',`alloted` = '1',`genby` = '1535', `leadstatus` = '-34-,', `callbackdate` = '2019-09-25', `read` = '0' WHERE `id` = '22484307' AND `alloted` = '0' AND `leadsource` = '29' AND `delete` = '0' AND `ownerid` = '0' AND `oldlead` != '1'
```

It's updating again with the same id and replacing data with millisec difference here is log 
[image]

full screenshot

[image]

Comment: I assume your log show the queries that were executed/sent by your client. It did not mean that it successfully updated the row. MySQL will respond with how many rows have been changed, you may want to check/log that. Your update changes `ownerid`, and the condition includes `ownerid = 0`, so only one of these updates should actually change something. If both actually updated, clarify that. If your app shall send that request/if it should/can show/receive an error will depend on your application (e.g. locking before updating/checking response and throw error if no rows were updated)

Comment: both are updating, the second one replaces previous changes.  and these queries were concurrently executed by two different users. . .i don't know why row lock is not working @Solarflare

Comment: How did you verify that both queries where actually updating? This would be a bug in the server, and it is unlikely you encountered this, as this a very very elementary and well tested functionality of how MySQL works. Instead, I could imagine that your logs (where do they come from?) are not in the order the queries were actually executed by the server (e.g. there is no guarantee across different connections), so you may e.g. just assume that, because the current value is 1535, that the first one (setting it to 1548) was also executed, but it probably wasn't. Can you verify that?

Comment: Owner_id changes, so I don't understand what you mean by a) `stops working`, and b) `this query is updated`

Comment: I am running an insert query just after each update in another table with the relation between them I have conferned that second query replaced previous owner id

Comment: I have updated screenshots.

Comment: Your screenshot only show that you ran additional inserts, but a) not if they failed or b) how the relation looks like (e.g. a foreign key `(subject, updatedby)` would surprise me (in general, not knowing your details)) or c) why that would make a predication about the previous update. I can only repeat: what you are describing should technically not be possible, so it's far more likely that either what you think is happening isn't actually happening or that we are misundertanding your description. So you need to add more details. (E.g. what is logging/how did you verify/the foreign key).

Comment: you were right second query is only running successfully not executing anything in that table I have put a check on running status not on execution status. thank you for your time sir . . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was only checking query execution status not affected status adding that resolved issue thanks all for time `mysqli_affected_rows($con)` thank you @Solarflare

```
$updateStatus=mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE `contact` SET `ownerid` = '$loggeduserid',`alloted` = '1',`genby` = '$loggeduserid', `leadstatus` = '-34-,', `callbackdate` = '$date', `read` = '0' WHERE `id` = '$row[0]' AND `alloted` = '0' AND `leadsource` = '$leadS' AND `delete` = '0' AND `ownerid` = '0' AND `oldlead` != '1'") or die(mysqli_error($con));
            if(mysqli_affected_rows($con) AND $updateStatus)
            {
            }
```